# Alternative for sysdepends in Sybase IQ

Tags: sap-iq

I would like to find out the dependencies of a stored procedure in Sybase IQ, considering that it does not seem to have sysdepends, can any one let me know how to list the dependencies for a given stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

In Sybase IQ, the dependency information is held in the [SYSDEPENDENCY](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/saiq-sysdependency-system-view.html) system view.  To find dependency information, you can join SYSDEPENDENCY, SYSOBJECT, and SYSPROCS to find dependencies of your stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to tell me which tables to join with?
Tried this, but it came back with empty result set.

select * from sysdependency sd, sysobjects so where (ref_object_id = id or dep_object_id=id ) and name='mysp'

Comment: *sysobjects* is an ASE compatability view. I would use *sysobject* instead, which is the IQ object view. `name` is not a column in either of those tables, so you may have to add in the *sysprocs* to get what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what i found on the sybase iq manual
   When you have a view referencing another table/view , the
link between both objects is now stored in the SYSDEPENDENCY table

Comment: I don't have my IQ system here, so I can't test out alternatives, sorry.  You should still be able to find what you are looking for using those tables, but it may require a bit more SQL trickery.

Comment: I think the SYSDEPENDENCY may only have Table/Colunmn and View dependencies.  I just trying JOINing SYSPROCEDURE with SYSDEPENDENCY and I cannot find any stored proc object ids in SYSDEPENDENCY on my system.  ...FYI

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while, but thought someone might benefit from this.

```
select soRef.name, soRef.type, soRef.id,suRef.user_name, soDep.name, soDep.type, 
suDep.user_name, soDep.id from SYSDEPENDENCY sd 
join sysobjects soREf on  soRef.id=sd.ref_object_id
join sysobjects soDep on  soDep.id=sd.dep_object_id
join sysuser suRef on suRef.user_id=soREF.uid
join sysuser suDep on suDep.user_id=soDep.uid
where suRef.user_name='myusername'
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no system procedure to find the dependencies of a proc in sybase IQ.
sysdependency contains the info for only the views so its not much of help in this scenario.

You might try to do it using unix script , where you can search all the tables which are used in the proc but again that is not a short sure solution.